# Add a preloading gif into script and page

Tags: jquery, function, load, preload

Please, I have a trouble with this code.
In short: I have a small web page with menu with 4 links: Every link load a page content into a div called “target”, using the jquery load function. I have add some fade in and fade Out effect for the pages. 
The problem is when I have a huge page with a lot of content to load, so I need to put an overlay and small preloader gif up the "target" div and into the code inside the js scripts, but I don’t  Know how. Please, could someone help me? Thanks..

Here the js function:

```
google.load('jquery', '1.4.2');
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

$('.nav a').click(function() {
    $('.nav a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#link1').click(function() {
    $('#target').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#target').load('content/1.html', function() {
            $('#target').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});

$('#link2').click(function() {
    $('#target').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#target').load('content/2.html', function() {
            $('#target').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an `Ajax request is about to be sent`, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, `jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event`.

> Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStart()
>   method are executed at this time.

css class of ajax loader

```
.preload{
  background:url('your gif loader image path') center no-repeat;
}
```

then this jquery will do the preload.

```
$('body').ajaxStart(function() {
   $('.overlay').css({"background":"black","opacity":"0.7"}).show().addClass('preload');
});
```

I assumed that you will have a transparent overlay div which will cover the page or a specific area when any ajax request happens, here i am adding a class named `preload` which will have a `background gif image of ajaxloader`.

Comment: Yes. This is the js script..and I've added an "overlay" div before the "target" div..but nothingh happen..and I can't see nothing when I preview in Chrome :-(